# ContentTemplate does not work with DXWindow?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I want to use a ContentTemplate property with my window. First I tried it with standard Window class:

```
<Window.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Hello world</TextBlock>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.ContentTemplate>
<Button>TestButton</Button>
```

This works the way I want:

[image]

Now try to do the same thing with DXWindow (I'm using DevExpress 10.2.4 version):

```
<dx:DXWindow.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Hello world</TextBlock>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</dx:DXWindow.ContentTemplate>
<Button>TestButton</Button>
```

But this does not work, looks like this property is ignored

[image]

Is it possible to fix this behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem with this xaml (it fails with error in the latest version (10.2.5)):

[The DXWindow.ContentTemplate with the ContentPresenter raises exception](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=B183767)

We will fix this issue in the future.

Could you please explain why you are using ContentTemplate and do not want to add both controls directly to DXWindow.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is only small example to demonstrate the problem. Actually I want to create base class for my dialog windows (with OK/Cancel/etc buttons, logo and so on). I have an DialogWindow class, inherited from DXWindow. And in the DialogWindow I set a ContentTemplate property. But nothing happens :(

Comment: I also tried a Template property, it works somehow, but replaces the template of DXWindow, so I lose title bar, control buttons.

Comment: Support Center says this bug is fixed. I can confirm this bug still exists in v2012 vol 1.8 / 1-Nov-2012